# Sequelize 6.27.0 and express 4.18.2, scheme.bulkCreate does not persist all data

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize for persistence on mysql version 8.0 database. I have an array of objects that I am getting from XLSX documents, all fine until I try to persist my dataset using the bulkCreate() method built into sequelize, which should receive an array of objects and insert them into the database. Only some of the field values are persisted, but the others are excluded and are persisted as null. This is my code:

```js
const catgs_scheme = connection.define(
     'indicator_category' ,
     {
         'id': {
             type: Sequelize.DataTypes.UUID,
             primaryKey: true
         },
         'Id_municipality': {
            type: Sequelize.DataTypes.UUID,
            references: {
                 model: 'municipality_info',
                 key: 'Id'
            }
         },
         'Category_name': Sequelize.STRING,
         'category_description' : Sequelize.STRING,
         'Count_indicators_by_category' : Sequelize.INTEGER
        
     }, {
         freezeTableName: true
     }
);
const indcds_scheme = connection.define(
     'indicator_category' ,
     {
         'id': {
             type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
             primaryKey: true,
             autoIncrement: true
         },
         'id_category': {
             type: Sequelize.DataTypes.UUID,
             references: {
                 model: 'indicator_category',
                 key: 'Id'
             }
          },
         'Indicator_name' : Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
         'Variable_Value': Sequelize.INTEGER,
         'last_update': Sequelize.DATE,
         'Start_date': Sequelize.DATEONLY
        
     }, {
         freezeTableName: true
     }
);
/* INNER JOIN category_indicator.category_id = category_indicator.id */
catgs_scheme. hasMany(indcds_scheme);
indcds_scheme.belongsTo(catgs_scheme, {
     foreignKey: "id_category"
});
const saveIndicatorEvents = async(dataDocument) =>{
     const saveDocumentData = indcds_scheme.bulkCreate(dataDocument)
     .then(result => console.log(result))
     .catch(error => {throw error})
     return saveDocumentData;
}
// method POST called in route: "/update"
const saveController = async(req, res) =>{
  const {data} = req.body;
  return saveIndicatorEvents(data);
}
```

Persistence data:

```json
[{
    Valor_de_variable: 14,
    'Última_actualización': 2021-07-21T05:00:16.000Z,
    Fecha_de_inicio: 2021-07-12T05:00:16.000Z,
    'Población_urbana': 12,
    'Población_rural': 2,
    Cantidad_masculino: 2,
    Cantidad_femenino: 12,
    Cantidad_otros: 0,
    'De 0 a 5': 0,
    'De 6 a 11': 0,
    'De 12 a 18': 0,
    'De 19 a 44': 10,
    'De 45 a 60': 2,
    'Mayor a 60': 2,
    'Descripción_indicador': 'Enfermedad respiratoria ...',
    'Id_categoría': 'e8d7af64-9f24-11ed-922d-940853629270',
    Id: 51
  },
  {
    Valor_de_variable: 9,
    'Última_actualización': 2021-07-28T05:00:16.000Z,
    Fecha_de_inicio: 2021-07-19T05:00:16.000Z,
    'Población_urbana': 8,
    'Población_rural': 1,
    Cantidad_masculino: 2,
    Cantidad_femenino: 7,
    Cantidad_otros: 0,
    'De 0 a 5': 0,
    'De 6 a 11': 0,
    'De 12 a 18': 0,
    'De 19 a 44': 6,
    'De 45 a 60': 2,
    'Mayor a 60': 1,
    'Descripción_indicador': 'Enfermedad respiratoria ...',
    'Id_categoría': 'e8d7af64-9f24-11ed-922d-940853629270',
    Id: 52
  },
]
```

Persistence data result:

[image]